# Correct Coordinate Referencing System for QGis Georeferencing of 1977 S. African Land Survey Maps

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, namibia

I'm trying to georeference some maps of Namibia and am having trouble. The projection stated on the map is the "Gauss Conform Central Meridian 15deg E. Bessel's Spheroid". I've tried using South African CRS : HBK_NO_15 and CAPE_NO_15 on the assumption that perhaps the "NO_15" refers to the central meridian. These are the closest I could find to the projection listed on the map.

Is this the right coordinate reference system, and if not does anyone have any idea what is?

I have also asked a related question as [Upside down result when I use QGis to georeference 1977 S. African Land Survey Maps of Namibia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252780)

Comment: Hi, is it a raster map or a shapefile maps?

Comment: I believe it's a raster map. It's a .tiff file.

Comment: Sample map here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8czw25voc74m13/2114BA.tif?dl=0

Comment: Just adding to AndreJ's comment, EPSG-wise, [22275](http://epsg.io/22275) may worth a try. I hope you find [this](http://www.durban.gov.za/City_Services/engineering%20unit/Surveying_Land_Information/Documents/SouthAfricanCoordinateSystems.pdf) interesting, too.

Comment: @Kazuhito 22275 uses a different ellipsoid (Clarke 1880 instead of Bessel Namibia). http://epsg.io/29375 should fit better.

Comment: @ColeRobertson please obey the one topic - one question rule of this site. You can edit your posting to just one question, and open another for the other. You might set links between them.

Comment: @AndreJ I have responded to your comments on the thread of a new question, [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252780/upside-down-result-when-i-use-qgis-to-georeference-1977-s-african-land-survey-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Kazuhito I have responded to your comments on the thread of a new question, [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252780/upside-down-result-when-i-use-qgis-to-georeference-1977-s-african-land-survey-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_NO_15` means North orientated. The CRS mostly used in South Africa and Namibia are South orientated, marked `Lo`. Positive `Lo`coordinates go to the West and South.

I suggest `Schwarzeck / Lo22/15` for your data, since HBK and CAPE use a different ellipsoid that is used only in South Africa.

Looking at your sample map, I see projected coordinates only as small map ticks at the border. So I suggest to better georeference using the degree coordinates of the corners (and maybe more points on the edges) and EPSG:4293 `Schwarzeck`. That CRS uses the same ellipsoid as Lo22/15. Note that South latitudes must be entered negative.