# Upside down result when I use QGis to georeference 1977 S. African Land Survey Maps of Namibia

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, namibia

I'm trying to georeference some maps of Namibia and am having trouble. The projection stated on the map is the "Gauss Conform Central Meridian 15deg E. Bessel's Spheroid". I've tried using South African CRS : HBK_NO_15 and CAPE_NO_15 on the assumption that perhaps the "NO_15" refers to the central meridian. However, when I rasterize the files, they are upside down.

Does anyone know why this would be?

Please see related question, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252701/correct-coordinate-referencing-system-for-qgis-georeferencing-of-1977-s-african).

Comment: @AndreJ you indicated [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252701/correct-coordinate-referencing-system-for-qgis-georeferencing-of-1977-s-african) that I should only enter my Southern degrees in the negative, however, [this](http://www.durban.gov.za/City_Services/engineering%20unit/Surveying_Land_Information/Documents/SouthAfricanCoordinateSystems.pdf) document indicates that both X and Y axes (East and North) should be entered in the negative. Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: The document refers to the projected coordinates in meters, not the degree coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIS software always uses positive coordinates to the right and up.

The Sounth African and Namibian `Lo` CRS avoid negative coordinates, using positive coordinates suthwards. That's the reason you see your map upside down.

If you use a north-up **project** CRS like UTM 33S or Web Mercator, your map is displayed north-up again. The **layer** CRS can be different.